# warning : The property 'Unloaded' does not exist on the type 'HyperlinkButton'

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I've recently inherited our Silverlight application from a departed colleague, along with a long list of bugs. I've never worked with Silverlight before...

I've added an 'Unloaded' event handler to an existing HyperlinkButton control, and it all works fine (i.e. the handler is called when the control is unloaded) except for a warning about the XAML when I build the project:

`warning : The property 'Unloaded' does not exist on the type 'HyperlinkButton' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.`

Googling, I've found examples of the generic error "warning : The property '{0}' does not exist on the type '{1}' in the XML namespace '{2}'", and they all seem to relate to people having upgraded to newer versions of the Silverlight SDK.

I assume that I need to update the xmlns reference to something newer than "2006", but does anyone know what I need to use? All the HyperlinkButton examples I can find online use that version, and I can't see anything in the MSDN documentation for the HyperlinkButton class either.

Comment: 2006 is the namespace currently being used.  What version of the Silverlight SDK do you have installed.  I'm unable to reproduce

Comment: v3.0 I think. I had to install various versions to get it building though, so I have v2.0 and v4.0 installed as well.

Comment: Actually, it's v2.0.30825.0 of System.Web.Silverlight.dll that gets deployed when the project is published, so it could be v2.0?

Comment: That dll is not actually a Silveright dll its a ASP.NET dll that contains the now much defunct Silverlight WebControl.  This control was designed to generate the html object tag to hold the silverlight plugin.  As of 3.0 this control was discontinued.  In VS2010 open the Silverlight project's property pages, on the Silverlight Tab what does the "Target Silverlight Version" say?

Comment: Actually still using VS2008, that might be relevant? Can't see a Silverlight target version on the project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project will be Silverlight 3, however the unloaded event for FrameworkElements was added in Silveright 4 hence the error you are getting.

Comment: But the handler is called successfully?

Comment: @Chris:  Good point but ultimately this is down to VS2008 not really understanding SL4.  If you close all the xaml windows in the designer do you still get the warning when you compile?

Comment: Yes, I just opened the project and there were no documents open, but when I compiled the warning was still shown.

Comment: I suppose there's nothing I can do to get rid of it until we upgrade then, thanks for your help.

Comment: Confirmed fixed after upgrading to VS2010 and Silverlight 4.